# Parse fire dispatch website feed to use discrete elements contained within

Tags: java, php, html, xml, parsing

I would like to be able to parse the following website and separate each dispatch page into discrete elements, such as time, data, address, and each individual unit dispatched to a call, etc.

http://lebanonema.org/pager/html/monitor.html

I would like to be able to use the discrete elements of a page and display them on a different website and such.

For example I would like to turn

this:

**20:15:09  22-07-13    POCSAG-1    West Cornwall Township SPANGLER RD HORSESHOE PIKE MV - Accident w/Injuries **NON EMERGENCY RESPONSE*** TK5 Fire-Box 37-03 EMS-Box 190-7 Station 05**

```
<tr>
<td class="COL2">20:15:09</td>
<td class="COL3">22-07-13</td>
<td class="COL4">POCSAG-1</td>
<td class="COL7">
West Cornwall Township SPANGLER RD HORSESHOE PIKE MV - Accident w/Injuries **NON EMERGENCY RESPONSE*** TK5 Fire-Box 37-03 EMS-Box 190-7
<span class="M">Station 05</span>
</td>
</tr>
```

into individual elements that I could somehow use on another website, such as the following:

```
time:20:15:09
date:22-07-13
pageid:POCSAG-1
address:West Cornwall Township SPANGLER RD HORSESHOE PIKE
incident:MV - Accident w/Injuries
additional_details:**NON EMERGENCY RESPONSE***
responding_unit_1:TK5
responding_unit_2:
responting_unit_3:
etc...
fire_box:37-03 
ems_box:190-7
station:7
```

I have moderate experience in HTML, CSS, and Java.  I am open to learning much more.  If someone can provide me with a snippet of code doing what I am asking, I should be able to learn enough from that in order to learn to complete what I am asking.

Please keep in mind that the page is constantly updated with pages, and that whatever method is used to do what I am asking, would need to accommodate such an environment.

Comment: you have java and php listed here, which language are you wanting to parse it in?

Comment: Feel free to try any of the languages you mentioned.

Comment: I am open to using any language.  I intend to learn as needed

Comment: I fear that your question may be too broad for this site. You need to choose a language, try for a solution, and failing that, come back with a specific answerable question.

Comment: Honestly though, I have no idea where to start.  I don't know if I should be using a programming language, or server side scripting or anything.  Any tips on how to get started?

Comment: If someone can show me a sample of how to do it in PHP, I will learn PHP and do it that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually asking two questions here. One is how to parse HTML (you find that outlined in [*How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641/367456) and as this has been answered extensively, I skip that part). The other is how to parse a string.

Parsing a string totally depends on the format the string has. This is normally done with [PHP's string functions](http://php.net/book.strings) and also with [PHP's regular expression functions](http://php.net/book.pcre). Consult the PHP manual for more information about these.

Next to the functions used as I have already outlined, you need as well the format specification of the string. So far, your question only contains *examples* of the strings, however, the specification is missing which part is what and what the decision criteria is.

You need to specify first, and I would do that before writing the first line of code. In the end, you can then write it in any programming language you like. So it's not that important if PHP or Java, it's much more important you have properly specified how it works. You then encode that processing into code.

---

Some rough example code (excerpt), to demonstrate how it *could* be done in PHP:

```
$url = 'http://lebanonema.org/pager/html/monitor.html';

$buffer = file_get_contents($url);

$buffer = utf8_encode($buffer);

$config = [
    'doctype'    => 'omit',
    'output-xml' => 1,
];

$buffer = tidy_repair_string($buffer, $config, 'utf8');

$xml = simplexml_load_string($buffer);

$nodes = new DecoratingIterator(
    new SimpleXMLXPathIterator($xml, '//tr[count(td) > 1]'),
    'NodeParser'
);

foreach ($nodes as $index => $node) {
    echo $index, ': ', json_encode($node, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT), "\n";
}
```

Exemplary output:

```
0: {
    "date": "23-07-13",
    "time": "07:56:28",
    "pageid": "POCSAG-1",
    "text": "Jackson Township W LINCOLN AVE N LOCUST ST MV -\nAccident w\/Injuries FG-3 E30 R31 Fire-Box 30-01 EMS-Box 140-2",
    "station": "Station 31"
}
1: {
    "date": "23-07-13",
    "time": "07:56:26",
    "pageid": "POCSAG-1",
    "text": "Jackson Township W LINCOLN AVE N LOCUST ST MV -\nAccident w\/Injuries FG-3 E30 R31 Fire-Box 30-01 EMS-Box 140-2",
    "station": "Station 30"
}
2: {
    "date": "23-07-13",
    "time": "07:56:25",
    "pageid": "POCSAG-1",
    "text": "Jackson Township W LINCOLN AVE N LOCUST ST MV -\nAccident w\/Injuries FG-3 E30 R31 Fire-Box 30-01 EMS-Box 140-2",
    "station": "Sta 31 Siren"
}

...

497: {
    "date": "22-07-13",
    "time": "12:21:27",
    "pageid": "POCSAG-1",
    "text": "South Lebanon Township 1700 S LINCOLN AVE VA\nMedical CenterAFA - Auto Fire Alarm FG-4 E25 E26 W36 R25 TK26 TK36\nAmbCo190 Fire-Box 25-08 EMS-Box 190-4",
    "station": "Station 26"
}
498: {
    "date": "22-07-13",
    "time": "12:21:20",
    "pageid": "POCSAG-1",
    "text": "South Lebanon Township 1700 S LINCOLN AVE VA\nMedical CenterAFA - Auto Fire Alarm FG-4 E25 E26 W36 R25 TK26 TK36\nAmbCo190 Fire-Box 25-08 EMS-Box 190-4",
    "station": "Station 25"
}
499: {
    "date": "22-07-13",
    "time": "12:18:19",
    "pageid": "POCSAG-1",
    "text": "Company 34 Correction..No Training TOMORROW\nnight..Training Will Be Held Thursday At 1830",
    "station": "Station 34"
}
```

This example also shows, that you need to deal with more than just the parsing, this is for example cleaning up invalid HTML ([in PHP Tidy can be used](http://php.net/book.tidy) for this) and dealing with charset encodings.

The `NodeParser` object is just overloading a concrete `<TR>` element given back by the `xpath()` operation - this is [basic SimpleXML parsing](http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic) and has been outlined previously. As a bonus this object implements the [`JsonSerializable` interface](http://php.net/class.JsonSerializable) so that it can be easily converted / displayed.

Using a parser-object allows you to change and tweak the parsing over time. E.g. as this example code shows, the text so far is not been parsed further on (as the specification is missing).

I hope this is helpful and showing how it *could* be done at least.

Comment: I tried running your code and could not get it to run.  What do I need to be able to get it to run?  I started a php tutorial on w3schools.com and the samples I tried on there all run, but I cannot get your code to run.  Here is the page http://bentsh.com/php_learning/php_dispatch_log_TEST.php and here is one of the pages I created from the tutorial http://bentsh.com/php_learning/something.php

Comment: Start with more simple PHP to get started. Also use PHP on the commandline, so you can execute it faster for testing / get results more quickier. As written the example is exemplary, it makes use of classes which are undefined in the example. Define them. Also see [*Iterator Garden*](https://github.com/hakre/Iterator-Garden) it has some of these. And ensure you've got the Tidy PHP extension.